# Uploading picture with paperclip for existing company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a picture model using paperclip

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", 
                                      thumb: "100x100>" }, 
                                      default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type:
                                                          ["image/jpg", 
                                                           "image/jpeg", 
                                                           "image/png"] }
end
```

And a company model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :logo_image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
  has_and_belongs_to_many :primary_categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many :secondary_categories
  has_many :pictures, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true

end
```

I'm using paperclip to load a logo image for company but the picture model will also use paperclip to store multiple photos for a company. I am able to attach multiple images to a company when I initially create a new company using nested attributes I get from the cocoon gem. I am trying to separate the concerns. When I create a company, I won't add photos. I will add photos when I visit the company show page and click on a link to take me to companies/:id/pictures path. Here will store my photos for the company and a form to upload new photos.

My initial attempt is not allowing me to upload photos even though I get a notice that the photos are being uploaded.

In the companies/:id/pictures I have the form

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for([:admin, @company], class: "form", html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
    <% if @company.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@company.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this company from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
        <% @company.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <h1>Add picture</h1>
      <%= f.fields_for :pictures do |image| %><br>
       <%= render 'picture_fields', f: image %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

In my pictures controller

```
class Admin::PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_company

  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      redirect_to admin_company_pictures_path(@picture), notice: 'Picture uploaded successfully.'
    else
      render :index
    end
  end

  def index
    @pictures = @company.pictures
    @picture = Picture.new
  end

  def destroy
    @picture = @company.pictures.find(params[:id])
    @picture.destroy
    redirect_to admin_company_pictures_url(@company)
  end

  private

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:image)
    end

    def set_company
      @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    end
end
```

The file upload button isn't even showing up and I'm only seeing the submit button. I feel like I'm over complicating it but if anyone has had to face a similar problem I'd appreciate any tips.